# app crash after changing the string

Tags: android, string

these are the main strings from the example

```
    String[] strings = {"CoderzHeaven","Google",
        "Microsoft", "Apple", "Yahoo","Samsung"};

    String[] subs = {"Heaven of all working codes ","Google sub",
        "Microsoft sub", "Apple sub", "Yahoo sub","Samsung sub"};

       int arr_images[] = { R.drawable.ds,
           R.drawable.ds, R.drawable.ds,
           R.drawable.ds, R.drawable.ds, R.drawable.ds};
```

**what i tried to do was to change the java string to string.xml in value folder**

```
    Resources res = getResources();
    String[] strings = res.getStringArray(R.array.SSolo);
```

....

```
    @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {    
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
```

here is the spinner...

```
        Spinner mySpinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner);
        mySpinner.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(Main.this, R.layout.row, strings));
```

and here is the rest of the code

```
    public class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String>{

    public MyAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,   String[] objects) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);
    }

    @Override
    public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView,ViewGroup parent) {
        return getCustomView(position, convertView, parent);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        return getCustomView(position, convertView, parent);
    }

    public View getCustomView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        LayoutInflater inflater=getLayoutInflater();
        View row=inflater.inflate(R.layout.row, parent, false);
        TextView label=(TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.company);
        label.setText(strings[position]);
        TextView sub=(TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.sub);
        sub.setText(subs[position]);
        ImageView icon=(ImageView)row.findViewById(R.id.image);
                    icon.setImageResource(arr_images[position]);

        return row;
    }
```

the app **crashed** when i tried to replace the strings above.

**and its giving me this error:**

> /AndroidRuntime(882): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to
>   instantiate activity
>   ComponentInfo{custom.spinner.myspinner/custom.spinner.myspinner.Main}:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException

and here is the main.xml..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/hello" />

<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spinner"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
    android:prompt="@string/prompt" />
```

and here is row.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/company"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dip"
    android:layout_marginTop="2dip"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/image"
    android:padding="3dip"
    android:text="CoderzHeaven"
    android:textColor="@drawable/red"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/sub"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/company"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dip"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/image"
    android:padding="2dip"
    android:text="Heaven of all working codes"
    android:textColor="@drawable/darkgrey" />
```

and here is the string.xml

```
<string name="app_name">CustomSpinnerDemo</string>
<string name="action_settings">Settings</string>

<string name="hello">CustomSpinner Demo from CoderzHeaven!</string>
<string name="prompt">  Select your Favourite  </string>
<drawable name="white">#ffffff</drawable>
<drawable name="black">#000000</drawable>
<drawable name="green">#347C2C</drawable>
<drawable name="pink">#FF00FF</drawable>
<drawable name="violet">#a020f0</drawable>
<drawable name="grey">#778899</drawable>
<drawable name="red">#C11B17</drawable>
<drawable name="yellow">#FFFF8C</drawable>
<drawable name="PowderBlue">#b0e0e6</drawable>
<drawable name="brown">#2F1700</drawable>
<drawable name="Hotpink">#7D2252</drawable>
<string name="select_Category">Select Category</string>
<drawable name="darkgrey">#606060</drawable>

<string-array name="SSolo">
    <item>CoderzHeaven</item>
    <item>Google</item>
    <item>Microsoft</item>
    <item>Apple</item>
    <item>Yahoo</item>        
    <item>Samsung</item>        
    </string-array>
```

Comment: Please post the rest of the null pointer exception.

Comment: there is no null pointer exception.

Comment: Try first with replacing `public class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String>{` with `public class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter{`.

Comment: Also, paste the code where you use `setContentView`. In it, you should be including the `layout` of the spinner too.

Comment: can somebody fix this crashing or give me some advice.. i tried every thing i know!!! the app still crashing :(

Comment: Here is all codes from the source:  [link](http://www.coderzheaven.com/2011/07/18/customizing-a-spinner-in-android/)

Answer (score 0):

You haven't posted the xml version of your string array, but it looks as though you may not have
defined it correctly. In any case, your array adapter is definitely wrong for an string array defined in resources . This is a working example:

```
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter1 = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.maths_subject_area, R.layout.custom_spinner);
```

and define this in the res/values folder (not directly in strings.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string-array name="maths_subject_area">
        <item>item 1</item>
        <item>item 2</item>
        <item>item 3</item>
        <item>item 4</item>
        <item>item 5</item>        
    </string-array>
</resources>
```

and here is my custom_spinner if you want to use it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<TextView  
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:textSize="@dimen/text_size"
android:gravity="left"           
android:padding="5dip"
/>
```

Comment: Hello... i did post the link from the source.. and this is the address... http://www.coderzheaven.com/2011/07/18/customizing-a-spinner-in-android/

Comment: Oh ... well I was expecting to see it in xml, which is part of your problem.

Comment: i just post the xml also

Comment: I'm sorry, but you have not understood my post. I have told you what is wrong and I have given you a working solution. Please read it again, and ask someone to explain it to you if you still do not understand.